# Defining Gender and Status datatypes in Java and DB design

Tags: java, database-design, enums

I have doubt defining fields as gender and status. I'm using Postgre Sql and JPA and I ask you what are best practice to design this kind of data types

I opt for both `Enum` Class (enumerated as `String`) and datatype for both gender and status, e.g.:

- Gender: MALE, FEMALE
- Status : PENDING, ENABLED, DISABLED

I found  different ways but I'm still unsure for a scalable and performant solution

Comment: FYI that first one's a whole kettle of fish.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what?

Comment: Defining gender as a binary choice. See for example http://www.mrs.org.uk/pdf/Guidance%20on%20Collecting%20Data%20on%20Sex%20and%20Gender.pdf

Comment: Both for gender and status? And how for Java Entity class? @jonrsharpe

Comment: I can't tell you about status, that seems like a concern for your specific domain. Is your question really just about enums in JPA? Have you identified a specific problem.

Comment: Yes but I'm looking for a JPA solution without neglecting the database design

Comment: This is one of the two default ways to map enums. If it does what you want, then go with it. Why would that be cause a scalability or performance problem? Why worry even before you have a performance problem? Why would it be different from all the other cases where you store a string in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I chose a smallint column in database table and Integer field for Entity class to manage both status and gender resolving it on frontend using a resource bundle so it can be portable for all kind of application and frontend choice.